# display a list of buttons in a grid

Tags: xaml, xamarin, binding, datagrid, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to create a grid of buttons that displays them 5 each row. i'm trying tu use the nuget Xamarin.Forms.Datagrid for this. but it is not really working. i'm getting a null reference in part of the mono code says the error. the way the datagrid works is kinda hard for me to understand. this is my code.

XAML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="CashRegisterApp.Pages.InventoryPage"
             xmlns:dg="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.DataGrid;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.DataGrid">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <ScrollView>
            <dg:DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Buttons}" SelectionEnabled="True" RowHeight="250" Columns="5">
                <dg:DataGrid></dg:DataGrid>
            </dg:DataGrid>
        </ScrollView>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Class

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using CashRegisterApp.Annotations;
using CashRegisterApp.Pages.Components;
using FreshMvvm;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace CashRegisterApp.ViewModels
{
    public class InventoryViewModel : FreshBasePageModel, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private List<Button> _buttons;
        public List<Button> Buttons
        {
            get { return _buttons; }
            set { _buttons = value; OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Buttons)); }
        }

        public InventoryViewModel()
        {
            Buttons = LoadInventory();
        }
        public List<Button> LoadInventory()
        {
            var buttons = new List<Button>();

            buttons.Add(new AddFolderButton());
            buttons.Add(new AddItemButton());

            return buttons;
        }

        public void OnItemSelect()
        {

        }

        public new event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: why wouldn't you just use the built-in Grid layout for this?

Comment: the list has a dynamic amount of items. it can be a real pain to set this up. since u need to give the row and column for each item. this can be done, but is not really a pretty way of doing things. so i was hoping to be able to create it with this so it looks neat in code atleast

Comment: You really shouldn't have UI code (Button) in your ViewModel. It kind of defeats the purpose of the MVVM pattern. I would suggest trying to get that code out of the ViewModel

Comment: @BjornFontaine maybe so, but that doesn't mean that DataGrid is the answer.  Writing a loop to populate a grid with a dynamic number of buttons is pretty straightforward, although it may not be the prettiest code

Comment: Can you share some graphical view of the layout you want as output? someone can help to build a dynamic UI as you want.